# How to make a field auto increment in ActiveAndroid ORM

Tags: android, activeandroid

How can I make an integer or long field to be auto-incremented using annotation.

Comment: auto incremented under what trigger? new class creation, function call,...?

Comment: when we call save method of a new instance of Model subclass

Answer (score 1):

As we can read in a [documentation](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Creating-your-database-model):

> One important thing to note is that ActiveAndroid creates an **id field**
>   for your tables. This field is an **auto-incrementing primary key**.

Maybe accessing auto-generated primary key will be enough for you?

Moreover, if you would like to create custom primary key in you model, you can check solution mentioned in [GitHub issue connected with ActiveAndroid](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/issues/22#issuecomment-81670905), which looks like this:

```
@Table(name = "Items", id = "clientId")
public class Item extends Model {
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
}
```

Then, id field is custom primary key, which will be auto-incremented.

Answer (score 0):

In case of **ActiveAndroid** ORM you do not need to write **id column** in model, It will automatic generate **auto incremented** value and you can simply use it.
I am giving a sample model below-

```
@Table(name="Items")
public class Item extends Model{
    @Column(name="name")
    public String name;
}
```

Instead of

```
@Table(name="Items")
public class Item extends Model{
    @Column(name="Id")
    public long id;
    @Column(name="name")
    public String name;
}
```

If **item** is an object of **Item** then you can simply get id by using

```
item.getId();
```

So, the correct model is first one. For reference you can [click here](https://github.com/mrasif/DemoPardomORM).